# sending an Arabic text in email

Tags: java

I have a problem sending an Arabic text in email with java language.

this is my message in properties file:

**mail.send=تجربة**

I use this syntax in jave :

```
    ResourceBundle dq_resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("nls.myfile_ar");

   String text= dq_resource.getString("mail.send")
```

but when I received email U have this text : **Ø§Ù?Ù?Ù?Ø¶Ù?Ø¹**

I try also in java with this code :

```
   String text= new String(dq_resource.getString("mail.send").getBytes(),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

but I have this text in mail :

**ا�?�?�?ض�?ع**

Comment: How do you send the email? Do you specify the charset encoding when sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a header for the mail, something like

`message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");`

`setHeader` is a method of the `Message` class that allows you to set a header.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution could be using **strings normally** ( without getBytes method ) changing the default encoding in your workspace for example eclipse.

Windows-->Preferences-->General-->workspace-->Text file encoding

Also you can try to convert **UTF-8 to UTF-16** .